# how to set header in laravel before firing a download

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set headers before firing a download.

Before I used to do something like this in plain php:

```
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
      readfile($path);
```

Now I want to still be able to set the same headers and call the laravel download function and pass my headers, something like:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

where the $headers variable should contain my header's. Anybody who has ever done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses)

You may use the header method to add a series of headers to the response before sending it back to the user:

```
return response($content)
            ->header('Content-Type', $type)
            ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')
            ->header('X-Header-Two', 'Header Value');
```

Or, you may use the withHeaders method to specify an array of headers to be added to the response:

```
return response($content)
            ->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => $type,
                'X-Header-One' => 'Header Value',
                'X-Header-Two' => 'Header Value',
            ]);
```

Comment: This was helpful, great! @Mr. Pyramid

Comment: @SamuelThomas pleasure!

Answer (score 10):

As simple as this

```php
$headers = [
    'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
];

return \Response::download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

Comment: This was helpful, great! @Mohamed Kawsara

Answer (score 1):

Attaching Headers To Responses

Keep in mind that most response methods are chainable, allowing for the fluent construction of response instances. For example, you may use the header method to add a series of headers to the response before sending it back to the user:

```
return response($content)
            ->header('Content-Type', $type)
            ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')
            ->header('X-Header-Two', 'Header Value');
```

Or, you may use the withHeaders method to specify an array of headers to be added to the response:

```
return response($content)
            ->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => $type,
                'X-Header-One' => 'Header Value',
                'X-Header-Two' => 'Header Value',
            ]);
```

follow this link it will help you 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: This was helpful, great! @Umair Mehmood

Comment: Its ok bro, always be here to help you. Give thumbs up if you like it..