# Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::$original At File Download

Tags: laravel

I try to return a response()->file() but i get this Error Message:

```
Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::$original
```

My Code:

```
$headers = array(
   'Content-Type: image/png',
);

return response()->file(storage_path('app/folder/test.png'), $headers);
```

My Storage:

```
storage
  app
    public
    folder
      test.png
```

Comment: This is a odd one. I feel like this is a search/replace that occurred at the wrong place. Can you try reinstalling the vendors? If this doesn't work, can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Shouldn't your headers be a key value pair instead? So: `$headers = [ 'Content-Type' => 'image/png' ]`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219754/4613879